# Python: list to remove element

Tags: python, list

From the following list I inted to remove the first three elements from each list:

```
x = [(0,1,2,3,5), (0,13,2,6,9), (0,7,8,42,3), (6,9,4,5,6)]
print(x)
```

Expected Output list:

```
x = [(3,5), (6,9), (42,3), (5,6)]
```

What I tried:

```
#x.pop(0)  //that would remove the whole (0,1,2,3,5)
#x = [1: ]  //the would again eradicate (0,1,2,3,5)
```

Comment: `[item[3:] for item in x]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
y= [i[3:] for i in x ]
[(3, 5), (6, 9), (42, 3), (5, 6)]
```